# Android: How to set text animation in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, animation, android-viewpager, fragment

I want to start fade in animation when user swipes to next screen, but i can't get it to work properly. Problem is that animation starts at the same time on first and second screen, on third and fourth etc.

Here is my PageFragment;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Animation in;
    Animation out;

    in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    in.setDuration(2000);

    out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    out.setDuration(2000);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment_layout,container,false);
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String message = bundle.getString("count");
    textView.setText(message);
    textView.setAnimation(in);
    return view;
}}
```

SwipeAdapter

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    String[] historia = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("count", historia[i]);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);

}}
```

Thanks for any helpful answers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` with your `swipeAdapter` (as in `swipeAdapter.addOnPageChangeListener()`). Then you could move your animation stuff into `public void onPageSelected(int position)`. Don't forget to call those add/remove listeners in `onResume/onPause`)